# how to catch a packets from wifi that I am connected to ( or not connected to )?

Tags: wifi, wireshark

I have wifi connection, and I want to use something like wireshark to catch all the packages that my wifi router is listening to.

How can I do it?

If i want to catch packets from the router that I could not connect to - is it possible ?

Comment: The top result on Google is https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/WLAN which covers this scenario.

Comment: this is not right - because i want to catch all that packages .. now only my packages to/from the router

Comment: From that page: "If you're trying to capture network traffic that's not being sent to or from the machine running Wireshark or TShark, i.e. traffic between two or more other machines on an Ethernet segment, or are interested in 802.11 management or control packets, or are interested in radio-layer information about packets, you will probably have to capture in "monitor mode". This is discussed below."

Comment: ok - 10x ... but without monitor mode ? is it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your router probably can listen on only on one channel at once. To listen to every channel - assuming 2.4 GHz wifi networking (802.11b/g/n) - you will need 14 wifi interfaces, each one at one channel, listening in promiscuous mode.

You will need more than one computer, as your computer probably does not have enough USB ports, and a hub will not have enough bandwidth and power available to support a dozen wifi cards.

After setting 14 interfaces (wlan1 to wlan14) you can run this on any Linux with tcpdump installed:

```
for IFACE in $(seq 1 14) ; do
  tcpdump -i wlan${IFACE} -w dump.wlan${IFACE} -I &
  echo $! >> tcpdump.pid # save pid to a file
done
```

Parameter used:

**-i:** use the specified interface

**-w:** write on specified file

**-I:** turn on wifi monitor mode

To finish the capture, run this:

```
for PID in $(cat tcpdump.pid) ; do 
  kill $PID
done
```

Comment: Not sure the first half of this is really relevant. The OP seems to be asking how to capture packets from a specific router. For most SOHO devices at least, this is likely to only be on one channel, and you wouldn't (usually) actually use the router for this. You'd have to have a client device with a wireless card capable of "promiscuous mode" capture, and you may also need to do some decryption along the way.